# Schedule an Axios POST request

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, axios

I got a client that's periodically sending GET requests to get a status of a demand that would've been generated earlier.

If the demand is ready, the server would respond with the information the client requested and should schedule an Axios POST request X minutes later.

Now, I've tried using `Promises` and `setTimeout` but they don't seem to work. I'm wondering whether the `res.json` I'm using is causing some issues.

```
     api.get('/api-gitlab-launcher/request-status', async (gitlabRequest, res, next) => {
        requestNb = gitlabRequest.headers['request-nb']
        let obj = getRequestInfo(gitlabRequest, requestNb)
        if (obj.requestStatus === "Not found") {
            res.status(404)
            res.send("RequestNb doesn't exist!")
        } else if (obj.requestStatus === "Running") {
            res.status(400)
            res.send("Not finished yet")
        } else if (obj.requestStatus === "finished") {
            // This code will be scheduled to run after EXPIRATION_TIME
            setTimeout(async () => {
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append("token", DESTROY_TOKEN);
                data.append("ref", "terraform-v1");
                data.append("variables[LAST_PIPELINE_ID]", pipelineId);
                config = {
                    method: "POST",
                    url: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID_DESTROY}/trigger/pipeline`,
                    data: data,
                    headers: {
                        ...data.getHeaders(),
                    },
                };
                console.log('About to launch POST request')
                await axios(config).then(
                    () => {
                        console.log("Resources destroyed.");
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        console.log(`error : ${error}`);
                    }
                );
            }, EXPIRATION_TIME);

            res.status(200);
            res.json({ec2Link: obj.ec2InstanceLink});
        }
    }
)
```

Am I doing it right? Did something wrong? I'm open to all criticism.

EDIT : The Axios POST request works without the `setTimeout()` wrap :

```
START RequestId: 03ee88f5-4abc-4f63-a59c-faa877c4b9f4 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 03ee88f5-4abc-4f63-a59c-faa877c4b9f4
REPORT RequestId: 03ee88f5-4abc-4f63-a59c-faa877c4b9f4  Duration: 1396.87 ms    Billed Duration: 1400 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 91 MB  Init Duration: 585.65 ms    
START RequestId: 9ffcbec2-6445-422c-87b7-4a5164b0593b Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 9ffcbec2-6445-422c-87b7-4a5164b0593b
REPORT RequestId: 9ffcbec2-6445-422c-87b7-4a5164b0593b  Duration: 5.03 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 91 MB  
START RequestId: 3577932d-53ec-4ee0-bf4a-f8aee12eba67 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 3577932d-53ec-4ee0-bf4a-f8aee12eba67
REPORT RequestId: 3577932d-53ec-4ee0-bf4a-f8aee12eba67  Duration: 1.60 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 91 MB  
START RequestId: ab854edb-5a86-41b1-81de-8bec85a54ad2 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: ab854edb-5a86-41b1-81de-8bec85a54ad2
REPORT RequestId: ab854edb-5a86-41b1-81de-8bec85a54ad2  Duration: 210.82 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 92 MB  
START RequestId: 5f6ae638-ea84-4308-8ea5-6ae3d3fb0116 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 5f6ae638-ea84-4308-8ea5-6ae3d3fb0116
REPORT RequestId: 5f6ae638-ea84-4308-8ea5-6ae3d3fb0116  Duration: 516.74 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 93 MB  
START RequestId: ddeb01ae-c9f6-40b2-ace5-b8b47ed21ebe Version: $LATEST
2020-09-09T20:15:53.893Z    ddeb01ae-c9f6-40b2-ace5-b8b47ed21ebe    INFO    About to launch POST request
2020-09-09T20:15:54.644Z    ddeb01ae-c9f6-40b2-ace5-b8b47ed21ebe    INFO    Resources destroyed.
END RequestId: ddeb01ae-c9f6-40b2-ace5-b8b47ed21ebe
REPORT RequestId: ddeb01ae-c9f6-40b2-ace5-b8b47ed21ebe  Duration: 753.89 ms Billed Duration: 800 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 93 MB
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve with timeout in the middle of request handler?

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov, sorry I'd copied the wrong version of the code.
I'm trying to schedule the post request with a specific time, `EXPIRATION_TIME`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `else if` block as follows,

```js
else if (obj.requestStatus === "finished") {
    // This code will be scheduled to run after EXPIRATION_TIME
    setTimeout(async () => {
      let data = new FormData();
      data.append("token", DESTROY_TOKEN);
      data.append("ref", "terraform-v1");
      data.append("variables[LAST_PIPELINE_ID]", pipelineId);
      config = {
        method: "POST",
        url: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID_DESTROY}/trigger/pipeline`,
        data: data,
        headers: {
          ...data.getHeaders(),
        },
      };
      await axios(config).then(
        () => {
          console.log("Resources destroyed.");
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(`error : ${error}`);
        }
      );
    }, EXPIRATION_TIME);
  
    res.status(200);
    res.json({ ec2Link: obj.ec2InstanceLink });
  }
}
```

Note that `EXPIRATION_TIME` is in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work...
I tried adding a `console.log('blabla');` and nothing is displayed.

Comment: I've created a sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-shirley-db8mr . Let me know.

Comment: This is driving me crazy lol. The axios post alone works, wrapping it in an setTimeout doesn't make it work anymore.

Comment: Crazy! I did update the sandbox with an `axios` POST request example. If I find something I'll update as well.

Comment: I added the console.log without the `setTimeout()` wrap in the post.